# How to create a query processing (or execution) plan?

Tags: sql, database

Say if I wanted to create a theoretical query processing plan based on a theoretical database, how would I do that? Also, how would I go about determining the cost of a plan? I need to create one and determine the cost, but I can't seem to understand how to create one without obtaining one, since online it keeps telling me to obtain one. Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: The sql engine uses real tables, with real data and real statistics to generate a real plan.  I don't understand what it means to generate a theoretical plan with theoretical database.

Comment: We were told, for our coursework, to create a query processing plan for the following, without the data or database though.

Tables:
EMP(ENO, ENAME, TITLE, SALARY), PROJ(PNO, PTITLE)
WORKSON (ENO, PNO, ROLE)

Make a query processing plan for: 

SELECT ename, ptitle
FROM emp, workson, proj
WHERE emp.eno = workson.eno AND workson.pno = proj.pno AND role=’dbadmin

I'm just not sure how I would go about it without the data?

Answer (score 0):

Your theoretical database needs to have costs associated with defined operations like "fetch a complete row", "do a comparison of two integers", "scan the complete table with n rows".

If you have that model, you can devise some way to fetch some specified data from a relation. You can not "obtain" this way since there's no real data and no pre-defined algorithms, so you have to create one yourself.

Unless you're doing this for theoretical computer science homework you're probably better of when you install *any* real database management system, look at it's query plan for the tables you've given and generalize from what you see there. Really, any open-source database will work to get you started.

For example, take a look at the [Postgresql Handbook](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/using-explain.html) and the `EXPLAIN` command. It will show you a query plan for the query you've given.

Comment: I am doing it for theoretical homework. The only thing we have been told is the database tabels and the select statement we should be working with. Am I missing something here? How would I actually do this, though? I missed this lecture and I am so confused.

Comment: Dunno much about your course but for me it would be totally acceptable in this case to go your teacher and ask for clarification. I'd still recommend trying it out on a real DBMS and describe the result in general terms. The example you've given is so simple almost all DBMS will create the same plan anyway.

Comment: Thank you, well we have been using phpMyAdmin and the explain SQL part seems to confuse me compared to what I have found online.